# Whats the meaning of"he appreciates with some of the intensity of a visitor from planet kepler" in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence

> **He appreciates with some of the intensity of a visitor from planet Kepler22b** in the constellation of Cygnus the bizarreness of how fingers interlace, how foldable they are, in what varied shapes and textures and etc.

Source: the good enough parents

"He" in these sentence is " Albercht Durer

Comment: There's no particular idiomatic usage. Kepler 22b is just an exoplanet that happens to be one of the more promising ones in the search for extraterrestrial life (small, the habitable zone, potentially with oceans.)

Comment: Please cite your source better. I searched online for "the good enough parents" (as well as "planet Kepler22b in the constellation of Cygnus the bizarreness") but got nothing relevant. You need to cite your quotation so that someone can find the source, either offline or online. If it's not available publicly (e.g., a student essay), then please note that.

Comment: What the author is trying to convey is that *Albrecht Durer's close observation of and fascination with the complexity of human fingers would be more expected of an extraterrestrial who is unfamiliar with the planet Earth than of an ordinary person*.  Fingers are something we tend to take for granted, but an alien with different anatomy might not!

Comment: OK,thanks.this book published in 2021 by the school of life.first published in the USA in 2022.

Comment: Sorry,l can't understand your explanation.would you please  explain again.

Comment: Have you looked at gotube's answer?  It's the same idea I was trying to convey, but goes into more detail.  I believe the last sentence in particular should help you

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is confusing because a long prepositional phrase, "*with some of the intensity of a visitor from planet Kepler22b in the constellation of Cygnus*" comes between the main verb "*appreciates*" and its direct object "*the bizarreness of how fingers interlace, how foldable they are, in what varied shapes and textures and etc.*".

Written another way, it might be easier to understand:

> He appreciates the bizarreness of how fingers interlace, how foldable they are, in what varied shapes and textures and etc. **with some of the intensity of a visitor from planet Kepler22b in the constellation of Cygnus**.

The prepositional phrase in bold modifies "appreciates". It means Albrecht finds fingers more interesting than the average human -- but perhaps less interesting than an alien from another planet would find them.